# jquery + intellisense + vs2008 pro fails to load

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

i use win7 + VS2008 PRO to edit my blog (php) and i can't seem to get this work.

i tried installing the **patch** (inteli hot fix) but it says no need to install (i have pro sp1) this is the folder structure:

js
   common.js
   jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js
   jquery-1.3.2.js

i working on a blog (not asp or html) so i created a common.js file that i want to work on.
i tried to **referencing** (**no spaces**):
 /// reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" 
(openning and closing bracket were removed by stackoverflow code manager)

but i get this error:

*Error updating JScript IntelliSense: Client-side script IntelliSense information was not generated due to an error in an external script reference. C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\includes\js\common.js*

i have the official jquery-1.3.2.js jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js and yes i **removed the 2 at the end of vsdoc file name**  and tried both mini and normal js files and both failed to load.

i just want to see some intellisense within my js file - a blog doesn't have a masterpage or anthing. why can't i make this work.

also **updated** windows services including vs2008

also **reseted** all setting in vs2008

also **disabled** all plugins in vs2008

Comment: Was about to add a "remove the 2" answer... anyway, have you tried an aspx page with a link to jquery-1.3.2.js to see if perhaps the usage of php or a stand-alone js file are factors?

Comment: tried that with saving the source as html and referencing - didn't work

Comment: same problem a while back looked into a lot and no luck. Hope to see a good ans that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the [**correct patch**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) (redownload/execute to be 100% sure).
I have the pro version with SP1 too, and it worked.

Second, double check the closing bracket with "/", and be sure to put it inside the .js in which you are interested to have the documentation in (in your case, if i am not mistaken, it is *common.js*).

Very important: if the doc file is in another directory, you have to point it correctly, relatively to where the *common.js* file is.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

Comment: this what i always get when i try to install this patchL
http://bit.ly/9K4Hh

i am using win7 - maybe it's part of the problem. patch doesn't recognize the right registry entries. i am just shooting in the dark...

Comment: Blind shot: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Comment: you blind shot hit the target big time!! the sp1 i saw was for the vs2008 .net component and not for the whole suite. i installed the sp1 package and then the hotfix and it seems to be working perfectly!! thanks man. 
small question - it seems to be working for jQuery. is there a way to make it work with $?