# How to enable Jquery intellisense in the VS2008

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008

I downloaded `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js`.
I am working with VS2008.
I included those .js files into my file. but while using jquery intellisense is not coming. 
How to do that.I read the web site [jquery intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx). Even though i did like this i am not getting the intellisense. whats wrong in there. Please help me. I included in my file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>.
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the following statement on the Scottgu's blog...

> VS 2008 SP1 adds richer JavaScript intellisense support to Visual
>   Studio, and adds code completion support for a broad range of
>   JavaScript libraries.

The jQuery intellisense annotation support will work great with VS 2008 SP1.

First you need correct patch [KB958502 - JScript Editor support for “-vsdoc.js” IntelliSense doc. files](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736). Install it and use as:

my script tag said

```
<script type="text/javascript" source="Scripts/jquery-x.js"></script>
```

then follow these reference links:

[jquery + intellisense + vs2008 pro fails to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505705/jquery-intellisense-vs2008-pro-fails-to-load)
[Jquery and Intellisense in VS 2008 with hotfix and SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702791/jquery-and-intellisense-in-vs-2008-with-hotfix-and-sp1)
[jQuery Intellisense in VS 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx)
[jQuery and Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) 
[JQuery IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.ipona.com/james/archive/2008/02/15/JQuery-IntelliSense-in-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To detect the file as an intellisense, you need to have at least SP1 of Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2008 Express. You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc533448.aspx)

As per a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/10/28/rich-intellisense-for-jquery.aspx). You should do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>.
<% if(false) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to drop the intellisense file on the page you are working on i.e. add reference to the intellisense file. this only provides the intellisense in the IDE and has no effect on the execution of the page!

However, before publishing to production you should remove it's reference to avoid unnecessarily heavy page!

Comment: You just give the solution which cant resolve the problem... :) I included in my file but cant get the intellisense. I am asking is there any thing to change in VS settings etc..

Comment: You wrote included in VS but you didn't mention if you included it on the page which you have to, to get the intellisense to work. Thanks for the -1 btw :)

Comment: I didn't vote down bro... thanks for suggestion i will correct my question

Comment: Try this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx. It should do the trick, it tells you about installing a patch required to invoke the intellisense!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Visual Studio 2008 cannot cope with the .min.js editions of jQuery 1.7.x. Try to use the development versions (without the ".min" in their names). With them, IntelliSense does work. Just verified with jQuery-1.7.1.js and jQuery 1.7.1.min.js. 
In order to use the vsdoc files all you need to do is to have the vsdoc file in the same folder as the .js file, no need to include it (if your Visual Studio 2008 is up to date).